# Is my PC safe after DSA-4371?

Tags: linux, exploit, debian, apt

I used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

before I read  https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4371

There was I change that my PC got exploited/hacked/virused. 
So I used

```
chkrootkit
```

and deleted all that was infected
After that I reinstall all packages with changed debsums

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install $(debsums -c 2>&1 | grep -E -o 'from [^ ]* package' | cut -d\  -f2 | sort -u)
```

Is my PC safe now ? Is it possible to have some virus or stuff like that running on my PC ? How to remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

The [DSA-4371-1](https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4371) is a vulnerability that requires a man-in-the-middle between APT and a mirror. Of course this can happen, but it's not the only possible source of the infection. Reading the article made you extra cautious, and you ran `chkrootkit`, which then found something. If you didn't run `chkrootkit` shortly before, it may well be that those problems have been there longer. First thing is to rule this possibility out.

It's hard to know what has happened on your mirror unless they have published finding malicious content. If you have a snapshot backup of your system from time before 22 Jan 2019, you could test that version again with `chkrootkit` or similar. If the backup was clear, then this vulnerability in APT is likely the cause for your infection and you can run the system safely after recovering it from the clean backup.

If there's no clean backup, reinstalling the whole system is the only option, no matter how it was infected.

Answer (score 0):

The attacker might have installed additional software or modified some user specific startup script (.bashrc) or created a backdoor inside a web application or modified some custom scripts of the user. Given that none of this touches the intentionally installed Debian software or its configuration it is not covered by the method you propose. And `chkrootkit` will likely not find this either.

Using `chkrootkit` to remove the found infections and reinstalling infected packages will only bring some part of the system back into a known good state. The other part remains in an unknown state (i.e. potentially malicious or potentially safe)  and will stay this way unless you have information how the known good state for the rest should look like. This might be done by comparing it to a recent backup (before infection) or similar methods building on knowledge of the previous good state.

Comment: is there an article, guide or documentation How to check and remove malware/virus in case attacker might have installed additional software or modified some user specific startup script (.bashrc) or created a backdoor inside a web application or modified some custom scripts of the user ?

Comment: only way to be sure there is no more malware/virus is to reinstall ?

Comment: @user197878: See my updated answer. The only way to be really sure that no malicious changes were done to the system is to know what the system should look like - not only for the Debian packages and configuration but for all the other software and other files which might have been installed or created legally by users on the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you uninstalled the last upgrade as you showed, there is no problem.
After uninstalling it you can download the latest updates with wget or curl tools.
Then you can install with dpkg -i.